# Как правильно ссылать таблицу в БД саму на себя или, что то в этом роде?

Tags: sql

Есть изделие, которое записывается в таблицу и состоит из других изделий, находящихся в этой самой таблице, при этом данные изделия состоят из третьих изделий, находящихся в той же таблице, а они к примеру, состоят из материалов, которые тоже должны быть в этой таблице.

Comment: не все СУБД поддерживают иерархические запросы. Лучше уточнить какая СУБД интересует.

Comment: Может стоит создать дополнительную таблицу с двумя числовыми полями: `child` - id изделия, `parent` - id родителя (составляющей, запчасти). Для одного изделия несколько записей с одним `child` и разными `parent` из которых изделие состоит.

Comment: Спасибо за быстрый ответ. Сделаю два ID поля. Первое будет уникальным ключом узла, второе - ключом этого узла на ключ его сборки. Долго не доходило, как это работает.

Comment: Есть несколько способов хранения иерархических структур в БД. Например, в [этой](http://www.osp.ru/pcworld/2007/03/4199032/) статье описаны четыре способа. Выбирайте наиболее подходящий.

Answer (score 1):

Что бы не ограничивать себя ни в чем, сделаем две таблицы.
Одна таблица изделий/материалов products. С ней всё ясно и так.
Другая таблица комплектующих components. Эта таблица имеет две ссылки на таблицу изделий. product_id указывает на изделие, в состав которого или для производства которого используется другое изделие/материал, на которое указывает поле component_id.
Таким образом имеется возможность собирать изделия из нескольких комплектующих. И в тоже время одно и тоже изделие/материал может применяться для производства нескольких других изделий.

```
create table products (
    id int primary key,
    ...
);

create table components (
    id int primary key,
    product_id int foreign key references products(id),
    component_id int foregin key references products(id),
    ...
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Храните как обычное дерево. ID у вас уже есть, достаточно добавить в таблицу ParentId.

Теперь ParentId заполняете у дочерних элементов.

Если ParentId is null значит это элемент верхнего уровня, т.е. наименование изделия. Все остальные - его составные части.